# Missing text of "The Prophecy of The Chosen One"

Tags: star-wars-legends, jedi, prophecy, star-wars

Is there some canon source including completely the exact text of "The Prophecy of The Chosen One"? I am reading [The Jedi Path](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=2ztRuQAACAAJ&dq=isbn+9781452102276&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI1c6-2r2JxgIVzKGACh1GyQBu), but the pages containing the text are defaced, supposedly by Palpatine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog](http://geekosity.blogspot.com/2010/12/endnotes-for-star-wars-jedi-path-part-1.html) is written by one of the people who worked on the book.  He says that he did indeed write 3 pages worth of the prophecy, but only left a few bits and pieces in the finished text.  When they were working on the book, they wanted to include a section on the prophecy, so they contacted Lucasfilms for advice;  they were told that Lucasfilms planned to do something very interesting with the prophecy in the near future, and therefore, the book couldn't include anything about it.  The note from Luke was an afterthought, inserted when they realized that if they published a book with pages torn out, they'd have a nightmare on their hands- sellers returning shipments, consumers calling and complaining about it, complete confusion and a huge headache.  So they put the note in to let everyone know that the pages were meant to be that way.

Update:  I now have the Kindle edition of this book, and the pages in question are unreadable.  The first of these pages has what looks like a Post-It note reading:

> These pages were already corrupted when the book came into my possession.  I don't know who tried to suppress the prophecy, but it was most likely the Emperor.  - Luke

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> “When the shadow of the Bogan falls upon them, the Ashla will not desert them because in the time of greatest despair there shall come a savior, and he shall be known as the Son of the Suns.”
>   *-Sarus reciting a scripture regarding the Prophecy of the Chosen One*

The other name for the chosen one prophecy is "The son of suns". I don't think you will find exact text that is fictional to the star wars universe. There are probably a lot of fan fiction excerpts of the prophecy, but this is the best I could find in collaboration of [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One) and [swfanon.com](http://swfanon.wikia.com/wiki/Prophecy_of_the_Chosen_One).

I thought the fanon page was a little more helpful to tap into the unknown regions of the prophecy not shown in the movies. Haven't read the book you are in depth with so, sorry if I didn't help! I thought I'd give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks anyway. However the defaced text is three pages long in the book.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas holy crap thats huge! I got to get my butt to barnes and noble and get me some books!

Answer (score 4):

As Wad Cheber said, the author of [*The Jedi Path*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)), Daniel Wallace, [stated](http://geekosity.blogspot.com/2010/12/endnotes-for-star-wars-jedi-path-part-1.html) that it wasn't really intended to be seen. However, there seems to have been an oversight with the pages available for preview on the trade edition's [amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1452102279), where probably due to some quirk of the scanner and/or the process they used to print black marks over the text, the tone of the marks is visibly different from the tone of the text so you *can* read it there. Here's something about this I put in the "Behind the Scenes" section of [Chosen One/Legends wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One/Legends):

> The text visible on amazon is also garbled; it appears that parts of sentences from different parts of Wallace's original text have been stitched together in many lines. This can be taken as further evidence that the text was not really intended to be seen, in which case it probably shouldn't be taken to have any level of canonical value. That said, it is possible in many cases to figure out where the two parts have been stitched and reconstruct sentences or paragraphs from Wallace's original text, and it may be interesting to see his original conception of this part of the book. There are several sentences in italics that would appear to be Wallace's version of the Prophecy itself:
>
> *In the time of greatest despair,*
>
> *a child shall be born*
>
> *who will destroy the Sith*
>
> *and bring balance to the Force.*
>
> The remainder of the text would appear to be commentary, attributed at the beginning to "Grand Master Fae Coven". One sentence reads "The prophecy of the Chosen One is one of the oldest prophecies Mortis held in the ancient Holocrons." Another says that "Master Sooloot believed the prophecy dated from the First Great Schism, and that the line about the Sith was added later to refine the original text." Another says "The Chosen One would surely be a vessel of pure Force energy, someone whose father into existence by the midi-chlorians themselves." And there is a series of sentences that appear to discuss Fae Coven's ideas about what it means to "balance" the Force: "All Jedi students should understand that fulcrum 'balance' does not mean that good accepts the existence of evil, in the way that sunlight gives rise to shadow. The dark has nothing to do with balance. Balance is a bed of green algae that feeds a school of darters whose numbers are kept in check by bog gulpers. Balance is the circle of life present in monolith systems. But beware, the greed of the dark side acts like a cancer on the living Force and the Sith are its chief agents."

And here are some screenshots I took of the amazon page, with the contrast adjusted to make them a bit easier to read (click to enlarge):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, there's another Legends book titled [*Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_vs._Sith:_The_Essential_Guide_to_the_Force_(real-life_book)) which at the start of Part Six quotes a Jedi named [Tionne Solusar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tionne_Solusar) writing in the post-RotJ era (40 years after ANH), and she describes a different version of the prophecy, although she notes that her sources are unclear if this is the actual prophecy or a summary of it:

> The Great Holocron contains many references to the prophecy of the Chosen One:
>
> *A Jedi will come*
>
> *To destroy the Sith*
>
> *And bring balance to the Force.*
>
> Records are unclear about this prophecy's exact origin, or whether the above words were the actual prophecy or a concise interpretation. Several accounts indicate that the prophecy was the subject of debate as far back as twelve hundred years ago, but it may in fact be much older.

Comment: Great idea with the contrast adjustments!

Answer (score 3):

The old novelization for A New Hope (by George Lucas and Alan Dean Foster) has the "son of the suns" quote at the beginning and attributes it to the Whills:

"... And in the time of greatest
despair there shall come a savior,
and he shall be known as:
THE SON OF THE SUNS."
Journal of the Whills, 3:127

Answer (score 2):

I believe to have been able to put together the original sentences using the amazon ebook pages. The actual book text is just a garble of messages that one can't really make out. But as I was transcribing the ebook into paper, I realized I was just writing the same things over and over again. The book pages that are blocked out with the black marks are just a randomized version of an original paragraph. With a highlighter and a lot of patience, I managed to put together the pieces in the order they were originally written. This is what I believe the Prophecy of the Chosen one says.

**The Prophecy of the Chosen One**
*By the Grand Master Fae Coven*

The Jedi archives contain many prophecies. The prophecy of the Chosen One is one of the oldest prophecies of Mortis held in the ancient Holocrons. *In the time of great despair, a child shall be born who will destroy the Sith and bring balance to the force.* The chosen one would surely be a vessel of pure energy, someone who was fathered into existence by the midi-chlorians themselves to act as their agent. Such a being would be beyond the authority of the Jedi Council.

Master Sooloot believed the prophecy dated from the First Greath Schism, and that the line about the Sith was added later to refine the original text. 
Many will wonder whether the prophecy of the Chosen One still applies to modern time. After all, the shape-changing Sith have been extinct for nearly nine hundred years. But beware, the greed of the darkside acts like a cancer on the living force, and the Sith are its chief agents. The prophecy of the chosen one is both simple and seductive.  So although the prophecy may be true, the jedi must act as if it is not. Some may think the prophecy elements/entails that the jedi need do nothing to combat evil besides wait for the Chosen One to arrive. This temptation toward laziness should be shunned, for the Order exists to serve others. Responsibility does not lie with a single savior, but with the Jedi Order.

Jedi with the gift of future sight are able to see where a river empties into the ocean no matter what path or turn it may take along the way. All Jedi students able to see should understand that Fulcrum “balance” does not mean that good accepts the existence of evil in the way that sunlight gives rise to shadow. The dark has nothing to do with balance. Balance is a bed of green algae whose numbers are kept in check by bog-gulpers. Balance is the circle of life present in monolith systems.

The order that I placed these sentences in were by means of coherence. Some, but not all, of them were placed fairly near to one another. Even though I am fairly confident that these are the sentences hidden inside the text, I am unsure if this is the original order.

Comment: Nice reconstruction, but it might be worth putting "In the time of great despair, a child shall be born who will destory the Sith and bring balance to the Force" in italics, since that's how it's done in the original. It seems like those lines are the actual prophecy, and the rest is just commentary by Grand Master Fae Coven (as evidenced by the sentence mentioning the theory that 'the line about the Sith was added later to refine the original text').

Comment: Also, I would guess that the line "But beware, the greed of the dark side acts like a cancer" was specifically intended to go after "Balance is the circle of life present in monolith systems", since it always appears right after that line in the original. Plus, contrasting balanced ecosystems to the cancer of the Sith was probably inspired by George Lucas, you can see he contrasts "symbiosis" (a word for mutually beneficial ecological relationships) to cancer in the interview I quoted in the last paragraph of [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122476/22250).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just matched the text that was in here with the torn out book pages. I believe this is the right order and that we have the complete text that was skipped from the book.

> The Prophecy of the Chosen One By the Grand Master Fae Coven
>
> The Jedi archives contain many prophecies. Jedi with the gift of
>   future sight are able to see where a river empties into the ocean no
>   matter what path or turn it may take along the way.
>
> The prophecy of the Chosen One is one of the oldest prophecies of
>   Mortis held in the ancient Holocrons.   In the time of great despair,
>   a child shall be born who will destroy the Sith and bring balance to
>   the force.
>
> All Jedi students able to see should understand that fulcrum “balance”
>   does not mean that good accepts the existence of evil in the way that
>   sunlight gives rise to shadow. The dark has nothing to do with
>   balance. Balance is a bed of green algae that feeds a school of
>   darters whose numbers are kept in check by bog gulpers. Balance is the
>   circle of life present in monolith systems. But beware, the greed of
>   the darkside acts like a cancer on the living force, and the Sith are
>   its chief agents.
>
> The prophecy of the chosen one is both simple and seductive. Some may
>   think the prophecy elements/entails that the jedi need do nothing to
>   combat evil besides wait for the Chosen One to arrive. This temptation
>   toward laziness should be shunned, for the Order exists to serve
>   others. So although the prophecy may be true, the jedi must act as if
>   it is not. Responsibility does not lie with a single savior, but with
>   the Jedi Order.
>
> Many will wonder whether the prophecy of the Chosen One still applies
>   to modern time. After all, the shape-changing Sith have been extinct
>   for nearly nine hundred years. Master Sooloot believed the prophecy
>   dated from the First Greath Schism, and that the line about the Sith
>   was added later to refine the original text.
>
> The chosen one would surely be a vessel of pure energy, someone who
>   was fathered into existence by the midi-chlorians themselves to act as
>   their agent. Such a being would be beyond the authority of the Jedi
>   Council.

Comment: Where is this from?