# Who made the prophecy about the "Chosen One" in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, prophecy

Do we actually know who made the prophecy of the "Chosen One"?

Or, generally, do we know of any other prophecy or was anyone ever mentioned to have made a prophecy?

In the end, who was making the prophecies? The Jedi, who had knowledge and control of the force? Or maybe another race in the galaxy, that also had knowledge and control of the Force and thus the ability of making prophecies?

Is there an official/canon answer on this, or are we only able to speculate?

Comment: This is the hope of the desperates.All oppressed people have a prophecy like this, but none of them knows exactly who told it first. By the way, in the Jedi point of view, `balance` is the extinction of all Sith. My point of view, `balance` is good and evil in equal parts.

Comment: Professor Trelawney

Comment: @ Cearon O'Flynn: Ha!

Comment: @MagnoC i agree with you about the balance of the force, but still there has to be some clarification on how, who and when this prohecy was made, and in general who is able to make prophecies. Could it also be the dream of anakin about padme dying on childbirth be a kind of prophecy?

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn correct answer wrong movie :p

Comment: @hedgehog: good point. But if was an ancient Jedi who made this prophecy, it will sound more like an egocentric dream to me. An distortion of what is `balance` in essence. An excuse to extermination.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn: No! keep it. Was funny!

Comment: @MagnoC if it would be the case that prophecies can only be forseen in dreams, then you could be maybe right, but we dont know even that, it could be that there are various ways, of making a prophecy.Though i am not even sure if the dream that anakin had of padme dying in childbirth was a prophecy, or if it was a mind manipulation of the Sith Lord Sidius (Palpatine) in order to make anakin want to learn about immortality, thus wanting to join him and become a Sith Lord. Because dont forget, the only reason anakin joined palpatine as a sith lord was in order to try to save padme from dying.

Comment: @hedgehog: Yes! And don't forget: was only Anakin acts that causes this `dream` or `Sith mind trick` to become true, turning it into a `prophecy`. Much more like Neo and the broken jar on the Oracle. There is a prophecy to become true or a lie to become a prophecy?

Comment: @MagnoC it cannot be turned into prophecy if someone pushed it to happen. Then its called guessing or hoping.... It could be a prophecy but even though anakin failed to change it.

Comment: Hard to tell. The search of the chosen one (Star Wars and Matrix) is an interference. The searcher is pushing it to happen by doing a hard search and mainly telling `you're the chosen one` (said in Matrix and Star Wars to the poor found one). The danger is: `he start to believe`. No one searched for Jesus. He simply arrives.

Comment: @MagnoC yeah but it was the will of the force that led qui gon to go to tatouine, he didnt say, ok lets go to tatouine and i will also pick up the chosen one there..... ti just happened that he found him.... so the question still remains, who the heck made the prophecy....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### We don't know

Information about the Prophecy of the Chosen One is surprisingly scarce in canon.

In *The Phantom Menace*, the Jedi Masters speak of the prophecy in familiar terms, but do not reveal who first made it (if they even know):

> QUI-GON : A boy... his cells have the highest concentration of
>   midi-chlorians I have seen in a life form. It is possible he was
>   conceived by the midi-chlorians.
>
> MACE WINDU : You're referring to the prophesy of the one who will
>   bring balance to the Force...you believe it's this boy?
>
> QUI-GON : I don't presume...
>
> YODA : But you do! Revealed your opinion is.
>
> QUI-GON : I request the boy be tested.

In addition:

> MACE WINDU : He is too old. There is already too much anger in him.
>
> QUI-GON : He is the chosen one...you must see it.
>
> YODA : Clouded, this boy's future is. Masked by his youth.

and near the end of the movie:

> QUI-GON : Obi-Wan promise...promise me you'll train the boy...
>
> OBI-WAN : Yes, Master...
>
> QUI-GON : He is the chosen one...he will...bring balance...train him!

Similarly, in *Attack of the Clones*:

> MACE He has exceptional skills. The           Council is confident in its
>             decision, Obi-Wan. If the           prophecy is true, he will be the
>             one to bring balance to the Force.

It's pretty much more of the same in *Revenge of the Sith*:

> OBI-WAN: (continuing) . . . You were the Chosen One! It was said that
>   you would destroy the Sith, not join them. It was you who would bring
>   balance to the Force, not leave it in darkness.

The Chosen One is also mentioned in Season Three of *The Clone Wars*, in the episodes "Overlords," "Altar of Mortis," and "Ghosts of Mortis." All of these episodes speak in similar terms, alluding to the Prophecy of the Chosen One as something well-known, while saying nothing about the circumstances under which it was made.

For example, from "Overlords":

> QUI-GON: Three are here who seek Skywalker. They, like me, believe him to be
>   the chosen one.
>
> OBI-WAN: You were right. The force within him is stronger than any known Jedi.
>   I have trained him as well as I could, but he is still willful and
>   balance eludes him.
>
> QUI-GON: If he is the chosen one, he will discover it here.

That said, we can make a guess. According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43579/missing-text-of-the-prophecy-of-the-chosen-one?rq=1), which is based on *The Jedi Path* (which may no longer be canon), the Prophecy of the Chosen One was held in "Holocrons on Mortis." **Since Mortis was the planet of the Father, the Son, and the Daughter, three extremely powerful and very old Force-users from the *Clone Wars* episodes mentioned previously, it is possible that one of them made the prophecy.**

As for other prophecies, Force *Visions* have occurred before. The Sith Lord Darth Sidious was able to see the future to some extent. Rey experienced visions of the future when she touched Luke's lightsaber. Anakin apparently had visions, although they may have been sent by Darth Sidious. There are other such examples, but whether these qualify as "prophecy" may be a matter of opinion, since these are generally visions of near-future events, as opposed to verbal predictions of far-future events.

Comment: Ok so your answer for the prophecy of the chose one is that we dont know. What about other prophecies? do we have evidence that other prophecies were made, and if yes what do we know about that?

Comment: @hedgehog - There's some precedent for Force-users seeing the future. Whether it counts as prophecy is perhaps a matter of opinion.

Comment: isnt this actually the definition of a prophecy, forseen the future? so its official that only force users can forseen the future...?

Comment: @hedgehog - Well, I was thinking you might want more of a verbal prediction, rather than a *vision* per se. Yes, I suspect one must be a Force user to see the future.

Comment: Still, do we have a canon reference to this? or  a George Lucas reference? cause i was looking for a validation.

Comment: @hedgehog - No, I don't think there's canon proof that only Force users can see the future. The only people who have in canon are Force-users, though.

Comment: is there also said the ways that a prophecy can be forseen? e.g. through a dream or somehow else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39628/discussion-between-jonah-and-hedgehog).

Comment: @Jonah Isn't it called a Force vision? I thought I heard that term in one of the movies, but it's used by fans so much that I might've picked it up here on S&F somewhere.

Comment: @Kevin - Didn't I use the term Force Vision in my answer?

Comment: @Jonah I was merely responding to your last comment, calling it "Force vision" indicates only Force users can have them, no? So if the term is used in the movies (or other canon) somewhere that means it's a Force user specific thing.

Comment: @Kevin - That's what I suspect, yes. On the other hand, it could simply mean "comes from the Force."